# How can I create custom item in action sheet in SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift

My intention is to create action sheet similar to this in Maps app on iOS (after touching bottom right info button). I know how to add custom view but if I wish to add e.g. segmented controll or another item, do I have to add it via creating view with it and then present one as action sheet .view.addSubview or there is another, simplier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a UIActionSheet at all. That is a UIViewController presenting using a custom 1UIPresentationController1 and transitionDelegate. Its easy to tell because it takes over the bar and doesn't have the same style as a UIActionSheet.

you can read this tutorial
http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/

Comment: I programm only in swift as now and it might be hard for me understanding objective-c code but anyways you helped me a lot with understanding this one. Thank you a lot for the clue!